# Error indexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

My scirpt :

```
if 'recheck' == msg.lower():
    with open('Output.txt','r') as rr:
        contactArr = rr.readlines()
        for v in xrange(len(contactArr) -1,0,-1):
            num = re.sub(r'\n', "", contactArr[v])
            contacts.append(num)
            pass
        contacts = list(set(contacts))
        for z in range(len(contacts)):
            arg = contacts[z].split('|')
            if arg[1] == receiver.id :
                userList.append(arg[0])
                timelist.append(arg[2])
        uL = list(set(userList))
        # print uL
        for ll in range(len(uL)):
            try:
                getIndexUser = userList.index(uL[ll])
                timeSeen.append(strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime(int(timelist[getIndexUser]) / 1000)))
                recheckData.append(userList[getIndexUser])
            except IndexError:
                conName.append('nones')
                pass

        contactId = client._getContacts(recheckData)
        for v in range(len(recheckData)):
            dataResult.append(contactId[v].displayName + '['+timeSeen[v]+']')
            pass
        # # print len(recheckData)
        tukang = "V=ON Members=V\n[*]"
        grp = '\n[*] '.join(str(f) for f in dataResult)
        receiver.sendMessage("%s %s" % (tukang, grp))
```

But error in terminal :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "echobot.py", line 117, in <module>

    if arg[1] == receiver.id :

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can you help me?

Comment: If '|' wasn't present in the contacts[z], you will get arg as an array of only 1 element. In that case, invoking arg[1] would obviously fail.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from

```
arg = contacts[z].split('|')
if arg[1] == receiver.id :
    userList.append(arg[0])
    timelist.append(arg[2])
```

you should double check that your contacts are all formatted correctly.
According to this code, each contact should be formatted like

user|id|time

If each contact in contacts is not formatted exactly that way, this error will be thrown. It looks like your split('|') fucntion isn't finding any '|' to split on.